# Can I create a placeholder iPhone app?

Tags: iphone

I'm told you can reserve an iPhone app name for 90 days, can I get around this by putting a placeholder app that says "Coming soon"?

Comment: If the name is that great, register it as a trademark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apps that are not fully functional or that refer to functionality that is not available but "will be later" will be rejected by Apple.

EDIT: here are the guidelines.

http://developer.apple.com/appstore/guidelines.html

Comment: What can I do while I find the resources to build out the iPhone version of my brand? whats the smallest app i can make?>

Comment: What can you do?  Pray, work fast, don't tell anybody.    Register your brand with the trademark office.    Now that the app store is flooded with content, Apple's in the driver's seat.   Smallest app?   You could try to submit yet another calculator, but who knows, maybe that app would get bad reviews and spoil your brand?   When your "reserved name" expires, you could re-clain it again instantly.   What are the odds that someone's going to claim your name at the very moment your claim expires?

Comment: When your claimed name expires it becomes available to everyone except you. You can't re-claim it.

Comment: Really?  Well that makes sense to avoid "camping."  Thanks, didn't know that.

Answer (score 0):

No. Who would download an app that does such a thing?

Comment: I would. And I would tell others to do it to. There is no chance to get rid of thousands of one star ratings.

Comment: And uploading a non functional app is the way to avoid them? Apple would reject it, and you should hope they do. Which might be a strategy to keep your name, but I would still strongly advise against it. A better approach is to plan out your development stages and reserve your app name as it nears completion. If somebody takes in the meantime, well it's life. Pick another.